# How to use the UIStepper to control global variable?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I tried to control the `num` variable through `UIStepper`, but when I pressed the increase button,

It always start count from 0 not 10,

I am curious what did I miss in my code,

Thank you in advance for any comments

```
#import "ViewController.h"

int num = 10;

@interface ViewController ()

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *myLabel;
- (IBAction)myStepper:(UIStepper *)sender;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    _myLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", num];
}

- (IBAction)myStepper:(UIStepper *)sender {
    num = [sender value];
    _myLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", num];
}
@end
```

Comment: My advice... don't use global variables at all. There is always a much better way to approach things than global variables. Using them is normally a cause (or symptom) of a poor design structure. What is it you're trying to do with the global variable? Maybe I can help improve the design and use the stepper at the same time :D

Comment: You should declare your integer in your header file anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're never setting the value of the stepper to `num`. Either set it in Interface Builder's Attributes Inspector, or create an outlet to your stepper:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIStepper myStepper;
```

And then in `-viewDidLoad`, set it like this:

```
self.myStepper.value = num
```

As an aside, I would recommend against using a global variable. I would make a property for `num` instead.